# Is uniqueness of steady-state vector sufficient to regular transition matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

> If P is a transition matrix, then a **steady-state vector** for is a probability vector q such that $P\mathrm{q}=\mathrm{q}$.
>
> A transition matrix P is **regular** if some power $P^k$ contain only strictly positive entries.

We know that the steady-state vector is the eigenvector of P associated with the eignvalue 1.

So if rank(P-I)=Dim(P)-1, then the eigenvector of P which column sum is 1 (steady-state vector) will be unique.

Is uniqueness of steady-state vector sufficient to the regularness of P?

Answer (score 1):

Have already found a counterexample.

$$P_2=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0\\
0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0.5\\
0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0.5\\
0 & 0.5 & 0.5 & 0\\ 
\end{pmatrix}$$

with unique steady-state vector $(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25)^T$

Answer (score 0):

A simpler example:

A=[0 1; 1 0]

The population between two stats keep swapping. The only steady-state vector is [0.5, 0.5]